# Java 8 method reference to static void method

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Is there a way to refer static method that returns void?

i've tried this

```
public Function<Runnable, Void> runner = Platform::runLater;
```

but it will say "bad return type, cannot convert void to java.lang.Void"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your method has no return value, don't use the `Function` interface.

Use [Consumer`<Runnable>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) instead.

```
public Consumer<Runnable> runner = Platform::runLater;
```

It `represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no result.`

Comment: This awkward moment when i feel ashamed for my question :D

Comment: But for this specific case you might prefer [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) as it’s the natural `Runnable -> void` interface. That’s especially convenient as there are already API methods accepting an `Executor` where it makes sense.